# Check whether a property is unique based on a similar valued property for a list of objects in C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I saw many almost similar scenarios asked, but couldn't find a solution satisfying my need. I have a list of object and in that list,  I want to get  objects that has similar/duplicate property but with different value for another property in that object. 
For instance,

`List<Emp>`:

```
Emp.CubeNo      Emp.EmpId
------------------------------

A1                ABC    // get this
B1                XYZ
A1                EFG    // get this   
B2                XXZ
```

Similar to the case in the above example; assuming each employee has a unique CubeNo, I want to find the CubeNo assigned to multiple employees.

I am able to get the result with the following query; but I'm sure there is much  more elegant way to achieve this. Appreciate all the suggestions..

```
var idealList = (from g1 in Emp
   join g2 in Emp on g1.CubeNo equals g2.CubeNo 
        where g1.EmpId  != g2.EmpId  
        select new
        {
           Property1 = g1.EmpId ,
           Property2 = g2.CubeNo  
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Which "following queries"? Please provide a [mcve] - it's hard to understand your question at the moment.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet, thanks for the response. I've edited by question.

Comment: That's not a [mcve]... please provide something we can copy, paste, compile and run. That will avoid problems like "Thanks, but I'm sorry the above query didn't work for me" - we should be able to change your code (but not inputs) and see the expected output, at which point there's pretty high confidence that it's what you want.

Comment: I have modified my question. thank you!

Comment: But you *still* haven't provided a [mcve]. I'm afraid at this point I give up - there's only so many times I can ask for you to improve the question while you ignore the request.

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm pretty new to the community and I tried well to explain my scenario to get some suggestions or help. And I'm not here to test other's knowledge or waste their valuable time. Do you think giving bit more time to learn the community is too much of an ask? these down-votes are really discouraging. However, I do appreciate your time to look into my queries.. thnks!

Comment: The downvotes are *meant* to be discouraging (as well as signals for other members that the question isn't useful) - they're meant to discourage poor questions. Improve the question and the downvotes are likely to be removed or turned into upvotes. In terms of time - there was nothing stopping you from reading up on what the community expects before you asked your question. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for more details of how to write a good question. You can still edit this one, of course...

Comment: Although claiming you're "pretty new to the community" is interesting as you joined nearly two years ago. You may not have chosen to participate in the community much in those four years, but you can't claim that you didn't have the opportunity to find out what the community standards are.

Comment: I understand,. I will try to make the question more clearer and hope it will be useful for others as well.

Comment: I see you've edited it again, but I'm still not seeing a [mcve]. Let me be absolutely clear about this: I would want to see properly-formatted code that I can copy, paste into a new file, compile and run, showing some results that I can compare with results also listed in the question. (There's also the matter of "If you've already got it working, but you think there may be a more elegant approach, you should probably be posting it on Code Review. But I'd say the lack of a complete example is a bigger problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListOfObject.GroupBy(x=>x.Property1)
              .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
              .Select(x=>x.GroupBy(y=>y.Property2)
              .Where(t=>t.Count()==1))
              .Where(x=>x.Any())
              .SelectMany(x=>x.SelectMany(t=>t))
```

With sample class i have:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
}

var ListOfObject = new List<Class1>
{
    new Class1{Property1 = "A1", Property2 = "X1"},
    new Class1{Property1 = "B1", Property2 = "Y1"},
    new Class1{Property1 = "A1", Property2 = "Z1"},
    new Class1{Property1 = "B1", Property2 = "Y1"},
};
```

[image]

Comment: hi Maksim Simkin, thanks, but I'm sorry the above query didn't work for me.. :( . my first query was able to successfully filter out the duplicate scenarios but now I need to filter objects with same Property1 but different Property2 values from that list.

Comment: You wanted to have objects with same Property1 but different Property2, aren't you?  Could you give an example what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Hi Maksim, I've updated my question, thanks for your help!

Comment: @geecee  but your query gives me exact the same result as mine. Or am i using it wrong? I replaceed DuplicateField with Property1 and uniquefield with Property2

Comment: Hi Maksim, I truly appreciate your patience and effort to help me solve my challenge..  but I'm still getting lot more records then required with the code you shared. May be it is because of my poor way of laying out my requirement. but many thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add that your class sample is similar to what I'm trying.

Comment: @geecee  i couldn't  help you, if you want tell me, what  exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @Makim Simkin, I have updated the example in my question.. hope that helps in understanding the actual problem. Again, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @geece  i have updated the query to get only multiple items

Comment: @Maksim..You are awesome! that worked.. Thank you so much for helping me out with this.

Comment: I added the empty check in the second line @Maksim Simkin provided, like so; -  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key))   and it works like a charm. :)